# I want to learn how to find a file that has the following properties: Owned by a user, owned by a group and has size 33 bytes

Tags: linux

I'm currently doing OverTheWire Bandit challenges and I need your help. 
The challenge asks that I find a file that is: 
owned by user bandit7, owned by group bandit6, and 33 bytes in size.

I don't understand how I would do the first two, but the third would be; `find -size 33c`

How would I go about finding if a file is owned by user bandit7 AND owned by group bandit6? I'd prefer if you didn't give me the exact command, but where I could learn the commands as I want to actually learn how to do this and not be spoon-fed.

All of your help is massively appreciated. R

Comment: Have you looked at `man find` yet?

Comment: You can start with `find --help` and then move to `man find-`

Comment: Found an [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355360/how-to-display-file-properties-via-terminal), this script can run in loop. Hope this helps. You can modify the script according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
find dir -size 33c -user bandit7 -group bandit6
```

Comment: Permission denied? I did the command ```find /home -size 33c -user bandit7 -group bandit6``` a few files come up but they're all permission denied.. How would I go about this?

Comment: You can supress the error messages adding `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Comment: I did that and there was no output, confused..

Comment: You are running `find` as an ordinary user (probably yourself) but looking in a directory (`/home`) where you don't have permissions to look. You either need to run as root or you need to look in a directory where you *do* have permissions: try your own home directory: `find $HOME ....`.

Comment: Are you certain tha `user` and `group` exists?

Comment: 100% certain haha, it's an OverTheWire challenge.. I have the solution: ```find / -user bandit6 -group bandit7 -size -33c type -f 2>/dev/null ```  Thanks @NickD and @guillermo chamorro

Answer (score 1):

If you need to solve ***level6***, See below...

1. First, go to the ***root directory*** using "**cd /**" command.
2. Next, use following command.
   :- "**find . -size 33c -user bandit7 -group bandit6 | grep bandit7**"
3. Among a lot of Permission Denied errors, You can see a path "**./var/lib/dpkg/info/bandit7.password**".
4. Finnally, cat that path. "**cat ./var/lib/dpkg/info/bandit7.password**".
   Now, u have finished the ***level 6***.

Comment: (1) Why do `cd /` and `find . …` when you can do `find / …`?  (2) Why `grep bandit7`?  Yes, *it **happens** to be true* that the filename contains `bandit7`, but that information was not given in the challenge, so it could easily find the desired file and then not show it to you.  (3) Is `find … | grep` really the only way you know to find a file whose name contains a given string?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You have basically duplicated the other answer, filling in the details (sloppily) and adding the ```grep```, which is wrong.  Did you see the line in the question that says “I'd prefer if you didn't give me the exact command” and “I [do not] want to … be spoon-fed”?